# How to split a Tensorflow dataset into N number of slices

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensor, tensorflow-datasets

I have an audio file that I would like to split into N number of slices.
I was thinking of using a `dataset.map(function)`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def split_data(tensor):
 return tf.reshape(tensor=tensor, shape=(4, 1, 3))

data = tf.constant([[1,2,3, 1,2,3, 1,2,3, 1,2,3]])
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(data)
ds = ds.map(split_data)

iterator = ds.as_numpy_iterator()
```

The problem is that the result is a single tensor rather than a fragmented dataset:

```
print(iterator.next())
print(iterator.next())
```

The first print statement outputs:

```
[[[1 2 3]]

 [[1 2 3]]

 [[1 2 3]]

 [[1 2 3]]]
```

The second output throws an error because the iterator has reach its end. The two expected print statements would be:

```
[[1 2 3]]
[[1 2 3]]
```

Can someone help me split my dataset into N number of slices? I am unsure if map is the correct method to use since `map` performs an operation over each of the elements, and if I give it 1 element, it will output 1 element rather than the many slices that I want.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the datasets [`window` method.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#window)
Each "window" is a dataset that contains a subset of elements of the input dataset, and you can decide whether you want to drop the remainder or not.

Comment: That is a neat method but I do not think it was entirely what I wanted. Because we would still have to loop over an object. In the original code, we would have to loop over the first `ds` then do `split_data(ds.as_numpy_iterator().next())` but in the `window` option, we would loop over the window object. Unless there was a way to join all the window objects in on dataset. Nevertheless, I am probably going to have to loop over the first `ds` variable.